# How can I get the X509Certificate sent from the client in web service?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get client certificate in web service.

1. I add client certificate in proxy object and call web method `Verify`.

   ```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string certPath = "D:\\test.pfx";
       cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath,"pass");
       Service1 obj = new Service1();
       obj.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
       textBox2.Text = obj.Verify();
   }
   ```

Web Method in Web Service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Verify()
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Context.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
    bool test = cert.Verify();
    return test.ToString();

}
```

In finish with this error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.
```

I don't know why. I used [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894121/how-do-i-get-the-x509certificate-sent-from-the-client-in-web-service).

I test web service and client on localhost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528455/how-to-get-the-x509certificate-from-a-client-request?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to follow [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221093135/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/TimH/archive/2006/04/18/75477.aspx)?

> - Host the project from IIS - not the thin web server that is bundled with
>   VS2005.
>
>   - From within VS2005 select File - New Web Site.
>   - Select the Location of HTTP then enter the path eg:
>     http://localhost/MyWebSite.  Note that
>     you don't have to use HTTPS just yet
>     (I find it easier for development to
>     use HTTP then when deploying to UAT or
>     Production to use HTTPS).
> - Code up a test form.
> - Go into IIS Admin - right click on the new app (MyWebSite) and select
>   Properties.
> - On the Directory Security tab, click Edit... under 'Secure communications'.
> - Make sure 'Accept client certificates' is checked.
> - When you run your app - make sure you use HTTPS in the url eg:
>   https://localhost/MyWebSite

Comment: I don t  use SSL, I only want send client certificate on Web Service.
I configure access to the client certificate with tool WinHttpCertCfg.exe, but the error is same...I don t know why..

Comment: You can't send the certificate without using SSL.

Comment: If I don't use SSL, I don't send certificate ?? Why ?? I can't send any type od certificate ? *.cer, .*pfx? any type ? I don't believe..

Comment: The certificates are sent as part of the SSL protocol, not as part of the plain HTTP, so you really need to use HTTPS (HTTP+SSL).

Comment: to Filip Navara.. oh Sory, my wrong... I use own  secure comunication (based on soap extension + symetric cryptograhy), I try use client certificate only on aunthentification in web service.